# How to get product object from observer in product edit prepare form event?

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, event-observer, adminhtml, adminform

I want to create custom note for an attribute I added to the products, so I hooked an event `adminhtml_catalog_product_edit_prepare_form`, but I need the actually edited product object, how can I get that from the `$observer`?

(I could get the ID from URL and load it by myself, but I'm sure there is a way to get the already loaded object...)

Thanks,
   TeeCee :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get current product from registry like below

```
$values = Mage::registry('product')->getData();
```

hope this will work for you.

Comment: Yes, it works, thank You for this **FAST** answer! :)

Comment: Yup, I wanted to accept it already, but it is time limited. You were faster...
Still 6 minutes to go :)